# How to use customer ID in the Stripe Connect Charge Java API (managed account)?

Tags: stripe-connect

I am new to Stripe connect. I am trying to use Stripe connect to charge money to a source account and send it a destination account. The source parameter in the below code should accept the source account id as per the infomation at https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge-source. But I am getting the error com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such token: cus_xxxxxx where cus_xxxxxx is the customer id of one of the customer account in my main account.

```
    Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chargeParams.put("amount", 1000);
    chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
    chargeParams.put("source", ??);
    chargeParams.put("destination", DestinationAccountID);
    chargeParams.put("application_fee", 100);

    Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

Please let me know how I can implement this as this is giving error all the time. I Want to use customer id only and not the Token.